# Backbone: How can I call a parent parent view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I got following nested View structure:

```
LayoutView
  - SidebarView
    - ContactListView
      - ContactItemView
  - ContentView
```

Now imagine following situation:

A user clicks on a ContactItem. Now the ContactItem should call an event or something else which renders the profile of the clicked contact in the ContentView.

I have no idea how I could do this without breaking the flexibility...

Comment: Might be worth checking out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine//hh201955.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use Events to hook them together, rather than having the ContactItemView directly call the ContentView. As you're creating the views, each parent view can bind to the child view's events. Then when the click happens, it will bubble up through the chain until the appropriate view handles it.

Here's a simple example to show the general idea. I'm presenting this in the order that the event bubbling happens, which is hopefully a little bit clearer.

First, the ContactItemView gets the DOM click event and triggers a Backbone event for it.

```
//ContactItemView.js
events : {
   "click .contactName" : "click"
},

click : function(evt){
   this.trigger("clicked", this);
}
```

The ContactListView can listen for that and republish it:

```
//ContactListView.js    
render : function(){
 var itemView = new ContactItemView();
 itemView.on("clicked", this.itemClicked, this);
},

itemClicked : function(item){
  this.trigger("clicked", item);
}
```

The SidebarView listens for that event, and actually knows what to do with it:

```
//SidebarView.js    
render: function(){
  var listView = new ContactListView();
  this.contentView = new ContentView();
  listView.on(clicked, this.contactItemClicked, this);
},

contactItemClicked : function(contactItem){
   this.contentView.showMeAContact(contactItem.model); //or whatever
}
```

This way your ContactItemView doesn't know anything about the parent views, so it can be more flexible. The downside is it's a lot of boilerplate code. Maybe someone else will have a cleaner approach, but this does the trick for me.

Comment: Might make more sense to use a separate `Backbone.Events` for pub/sub (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/EnZNg/) so that the views don't have to know about each other, there might be other things that will care about the current contact as well and a central pub/sub object will make that much easier. And if the current contact needs to be a persistent application attribute then you just swap the Backbone.Events pub/sub object for a full blown Backbone.Model and everything keeps working as before but you get persistence almost for free.

Comment: That is a lot simpler and more concise. But it feels a bit like a global variable, which makes me leery of it. It also feels like you're breaking the encapsulation of the list & item views. I guess it depends on how much you value simplicity & brevity vs encapsulation.

Comment: Globals are a tool like any other, normally you'd have a global `app` object and then `app.pubsub` or `app.settings`. I don't see an encapsulation issue, the current contact could be an application-level property. Sometimes it makes sense for views to talk to each other, sometimes it makes more sense to decouple them by putting a dispatcher in the middle.

Comment: Hi, this sounds great. I will take a closer look about that

Comment: @muistooshort Where would you recommand to initialise such an global object when using requireJs? Into the bootstrapping file or into the layout view?

Comment: @kyogron: I don't use require.js so I can't give you a good answer, sorry. You'd want that initialization somewhere that will be executed before any other application code runs.

Comment: @muistooshort what do you use (commonJs, raw including)?

Comment: @kyogron: Pretty much raw including through the Rails asset pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use is an event aggregator which enables your views to subscribe to certain events.  This will allow you to decouple your views from each other. Your views don't need to know about each other, they just need to keep track of certain events. For a great tutorial on how to do this see [Derick Bailey's](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/) excellent post on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Backbone.Courier](https://github.com/rotundasoftware/backbone.courier). It is a light weight backbone plugin built for exactly the kind of "event bubbling" scenario you describe, making it easy for child views to communicate with parents, grandparents, etc., without need for trigger chains or global event aggregators.